# Identify conjugacy class of coset in factor group in GAP

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, gap, finitely-generated

I wish to use GAP to identify the conjugacy class of a given element $[g]$ in the factor group $G/H$ where $H$ is a finite-index normal subgroup of a finitely presented group $G$. I know how to compute a list of right coset representatives of $H$:

`T:=RightTransversal(G,H);`

and can determine to which coset $[g]$ a given element $g\in G$ belongs using `PositionCanonical(T,g)`.

To study the conjugacy classes of $G/H$, I construct the factor group and compute its conjugacy classes:

```
quot:=FactorGroup(G,H);
CC:=ConjugacyClasses(quot);
```

To check whether $[g]$ belongs to, say, the third conjugacy class of $G/H$, I thought of doing:

`IsConjugate(quot,RightCoset(H,g),Representative(CC[3]));`

but GAP returns an error message of the form:

```
Error, no 1st choice method found for `IsConjugate' on 3 arguments at /usr/local/gap-4.11.1/lib/methsel2.g:249 called from
IsConjugate( quot, RightCoset(...
```

which I've truncated at the end. Any suggestions on how to do this computation properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that GAP represents (for efficiency reasons) the factor group in a new way, i.e. its elements are not cosets (but e.g. permutations).
The key is to use the natural homomorphism:

```
nat:=NaturalHomomorphismByNormalSubgroup(G,H);
quot:=Image(nat,G);
CC:=ConjugacyClasses(quot);
```

and then either (analog to your command)

```
IsConjugate(quot,Image(nat,g),Representative(CC[3]));
```

or (shorter to type and potentially faster:

```
Image(nat,g) in CC[3]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.